# Scanner returning unwanted information when trying to use int = input.nextInt in leap year class

Tags: java, integer

I'm trying to write a program to check if a year entered by the user is a leap year. I thought what I had below was fine (though I do wish it would return to System.out.print("Please enter a leap year:"); when a year <= 1582 is entered, I'm not sure how to do that), but when I enter a number higher than 1582 I get the following:

```
run:
Please enter a leap year:1600
java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=4][match valid=true][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E] is a leap year.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

I don't understand why it's printing all of this out, I only want the number that the user entered. I'm new to programming so there is nothing readily obvious about this to me. Thanks, and here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYearCheck{
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
                
        System.out.print("Please enter a leap year:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int year = input.nextInt();
        
        if (year<=1582){
            System.out.println("An input of 1582 or less is not valid.");
        }    
                    
        else if (year%400==0){
            System.out.println(input + " is a leap year.");
            return;
        }
        
        else if (year%4==0 && year%100!=0){
            System.out.println(input + " is a leap year.");
            return;
        }
        
        else{
            System.out.println(input + " is not a leap year.");
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You are printing `input`. I think you meant to print `year`.

Comment: What is `input` at `System.out.println(input + " is a leap year.");`? (yes, proper naming of variables may save us some trouble).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println(year+"any extra string here");` your problem is that you are trying to print the scanner itself by printing `input`. Input is not the variable that holds the user input, you defined `year` to hold that information